# Cannot change hostname on raspberry pi

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

```
Error writting /ect/hostname: no such file or directory
```

I am currently getting that error when I follow [How to change raspberry pi hostname](http://www.howtogeek.com/167195/how-to-change-your-raspberry-pi-or-other-linux-devices-hostname/)

When I type **sudo nano /etc/hosts** I get a blank file, and when I type **sudo nano /etc/hostname** I also get a blank file. I have tried to save the new hostname in /ect/hostname but I get the error above. I am not a linux user normally so I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Did you try `hostname <name>`?

Comment: @Guido `hostname` will set the host's name only until next reboot. `/etc/hostname` is the proper place for a persistent setting. However, I guess it is just a typo in path as Blender said

Comment: Ohh... yep spelling error -.- Thank you for pointing that out. everything is working now.

Answer (score 0):

According to raspi-config you need to do these 3 steps

- Replace `/etc/hostname` with you new hostname
- Edit `/etc/hosts` to replace `127.0.1.1 $CURRENT_HOSTNAME` `127.0.1.1 $NEW_HOSTNAME`
- MUST reboot to see effect

This can be done quickly via below:

```
sudo raspi-config nonint do_hostname ${NEW_HOSTNAME}
sudo reboot # Must reboot to see change
```

This is since raspi-config is a bash script and has a noninteractive mode you can use. Of which as of now, this is what we are trying to trigger below:

```
do_hostname() {
  if [ "$INTERACTIVE" = True ]; then
    whiptail --msgbox "\
Please note: RFCs mandate that a hostname's labels \
may contain only the ASCII letters 'a' through 'z' (case-insensitive), 
the digits '0' through '9', and the hyphen.
Hostname labels cannot begin or end with a hyphen. 
No other symbols, punctuation characters, or blank spaces are permitted.\
" 20 70 1
  fi
  CURRENT_HOSTNAME=`cat /etc/hostname | tr -d " \t\n\r"`
  if [ "$INTERACTIVE" = True ]; then
    NEW_HOSTNAME=$(whiptail --inputbox "Please enter a hostname" 20 60 "$CURRENT_HOSTNAME" 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)
  else
    NEW_HOSTNAME=$1
    true
  fi
  if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo $NEW_HOSTNAME > /etc/hostname
    sed -i "s/127.0.1.1.*$CURRENT_HOSTNAME/127.0.1.1\t$NEW_HOSTNAME/g" /etc/hosts
    ASK_TO_REBOOT=1
  fi
}
```